# Array stores the incorrect variable value in a loop (Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm working with Pine Script, and I have encountered an issue where an array seems to store the same variable value when used in a loop. I have two methods, and the first method is showing the same results five times, which is incorrect. The second method, however, is showing different results each time, which is the behavior I expect.

Here are the two methods:

`variables declared`

```
fSma = 10
sSma = 44
a = array.new_int(0)
var int k = 0
int i = 1
```

`1st method (incorrect results)`

```
while i < 6
    fSma += 1
    sSma += 1
    k := f(fSma, sSma)
    array.push(a, k)
    i := i + 1

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, array.join(a, ','))
```

`2nd method (correct results but it's manual process so need to use in loop)`

```
while i < 6
    fSma += 5
    sSma += 5
    switch
        i == 1 => k := f(fSma, sSma)
        i == 2 => k := f(fSma, sSma)
        i == 3 => k := f(fSma, sSma)
        i == 4 => k := f(fSma, sSma)
        i == 5 => k := f(fSma, sSma)
    array.push(a, k)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, array.join(a, ','))
```

Expected Outcome:
In both methods, I expected the array a to store different values in each iteration of the loop, reflecting the results of the custom function f.

Actual Outcome:
The 1st method, however, seems to store the same values in the array for each iteration, whereas the 2nd method behaves as expected, storing different values in the array.

I'm seeking insights into why the 1st method might not be working as intended and any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.